# Ext js Numberfield in Chrome device Emulator allow type "e" (exponential)

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am having an issue with Ext JS number field.
It is allowed to type the letter "e" in a number field component when I am using a device in google chrome emulator.

Steps to reproduce the behavior:

1. Enter in this fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/36eh
2. Press F12 to open inspect mode.
3. Click on the Device icon to change to device mode.
4. Click to Run the fiddle again.
5. Type letter "e" in the number field component.
6. Verify that was possible to inform the letter "e" in device mode.

Have you guys ever seen this issue?

Thanks,
Renato Carvalho.

Comment: It is the exponential notation for example 1.2E10

Comment: Thanks Arthur! Is there some way to prevent that? And it is just happening on the device mode. I found this property "allowExponential" in sencha documentation, but it is just for classic toolkit and we are using modern toolkit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following dirty hack:

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    renderTo: document.body,
    items: [{
        xtype: 'numberfield',
        label: 'Decimal number',
        decimals: 2,
        decimalSeparator: ',',
        labelAlign: 'top',
        name: 'age',
        //inputType: 'number', // Instead of "click on the Device icon"
        // Our dirty hack/workaround 
        listeners: {
            keydown: function(cmp, e) {
                if(e.key() === 'e') {
                    e.stopEvent()
                }
            }
        }
    }]
});
```

Or you can use inputType: 'text' and filter the input, but it is more dirty way.. anyway if you will not find something more elegant, you can use this dirty hack.

Another solution:

```
<input type="number" onkeydown="javascript: return event.keyCode === 8 || event.keyCode === 46 ? true : !isNaN(Number(event.key))">
```

Comment: Thanks for your time Arthur! I will try this approach!

Comment: Thanks, Arthur, it worked for us. Send to me a donation link, I would like to pay you a beer for the all the times that you helped us! hehehehehe

Comment: I tested using the BrowserStack app and SwiftKey Keyboard, for this specific scenario we still have the problem. Seems like the key value is not recognized. Possibly I will need to use another solution. If I discover something I post here. Thanks

Comment: Have a look at the second solution.

Comment: Even using the second solution we still have the same issue for a device using SwiftKey Keyboard in google chrome. I think is a problem with Swiftkey and google chrome or BrowserStack App.

Comment: Arthur, it is working now. I used a hybrid solution. Basically, for the common keyboards, I kept the first solution using the onKeyDown event. Just for SwiftKey Keyboard scenario, I used the following function: `oninput="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');"`.